# Making data entry fields remember their values form one run to the next

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing a C++ MFC program, and I see programs that remember the last input values for some fields from one program run to the next. I could do this by saving it to a file and loading that and then repopulating, but is there another, quicker way of doing this, as I think I remember reading somewhere that these values could be stored in the registry? If anyone has an example or personal experiences, I would be very interested.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Define 'quicker'. Do you actually mean faster to program or faster to execute?

Comment: Faster to program, it's only a small program. I can do it via a file, but always interested to see if there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options out there

I personally don't like the registery and prefer to keep my program portable.
so what I can think of right now are
1- ini files

2- property files

3- SQL server

4- you can also synchronize the user settings via web server, but as @Jeeva mentioned there are security considerations

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll just stick it in a .ini file.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of values you want remember. If it is an configuration data you can use `config` files. If it is small application data you can use flat files with proprietary format. If it is huge data you can use a database like `SQL Server`.

Usually there is a debate about using [ini file vs registry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/was-the-windows-registry-a-good-idea.html).

Other things you want to consider is whether the data will be used across network. Whether you need to encrypt.

Comment: Thanks for the link about registry vs ini